# Detect current from moving charged plastic rod near wire

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, electromagnetic-induction

Here is my thought experiment. I take plastic rod and rub it with fur. It obtains negative charge. Now I move this rod and generate magnetic field (due to moving charge). I move this rod near the wire, so changing magnetic field will induce current in the wire. How can I detect the current in the wire? Ordinary multimeter (with 200 mA) is not sensitive enough.

P.S. So suggestion is to get more sensitive multimeter, but could anybody tell me what kind of sensitivity should I be looking for. Probably, the most sensitive will be too expensive.

Comment: Indeed you have answered your own question in that you know your 200 mA meter is not sensitive enough.  So either get a more sensitive meter or employ some sort of amplification process to detect the current.

Comment: @jwh20 Thank you for reply! Do you know how sensitive the multimeter should be ? I am worried that I do not have resource for the most sensitive one.

Comment: Let me suggest that you might do some rough calculations to determine the magnitude of the expected induced current and then determine what sensitivity you need.  A simple op-amp based amplifier circuit should get you whatever level of gain needed.  Remember also that you can coil your pickup wire so that you get more current induced from the same changing field.

Comment: @jwh20, thank for they reply. 1) I was thinking how to estimate charge on the rod and my main idea it so connect rod somehow to capacitor and then read voltage from capacitor. Getting charge from rod to capacitor is not obvious. I need some sort of metal mesh covering rod and they wire it to capacitor. 2) Simple op-amp amplifier looks like a chip and requires soldering. Is there simpler solution

Comment: @jwh20 3) I tried to coil the wire on my multimeter and it still does not even pick up current from moving toy magnet near by.  So unlikely it will pick up magnetic field from movement of charged rod. But thank you for coil suggestion, I will keep it in mind.